# Retrieve value on $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a code where I have to set `CSS` class to a tab when the children are clicked. I want to remember the `onclick` and then apply CSS to it when the child page loads.

```
<li>
   <h:outputLink  id="analyticsTab" value="#{mappSec.analyticsTab}" 
     rendered="true" >Analytics</h:outputLink>
   <ul class="header_dropdown_menu" id="menuList">
   <ui:repeat value="#{mappSec.analyticsMenus}" var="pages" >   
    <li>
       <a href="#{pages[1]}" onclick="analyticsCSS(); return false;" 
          id="#{pages[0].replaceAll('[^a-zA-Z0-9]','')}" target="_self" 
          class="hidden">#{pages[0]}</a>
    </li>
   </ui:repeat>
   </ul>
</li>
```

If any of the `<a>` tag gets clicked I have to apply a CSS on the page load to

```
<h:outputLink  id="analyticsTab"
```

So, how could I know after page load that `<a href>` tag was clicked?

Comment: Have a look at *localStorage*

Comment: It looks like your links are using #hash links.  Are you actually transferring pages when these are clicked?  Or is this some templating syntax I'm not aware of.

Comment: I am actually transferring to pages. It is a JSF syntax that I am using and I can very well navigate to other pages.

Comment: @Jonasw:  I already looked into localStorage but it won't solve my issue as there are multiple <li> tags, which would cause me to write unwanted redundant code to exclude all possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

"a:visited" https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp . Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. But, Thanks anyways!